# How do i unlock/reset my iPhone if the screen is completely frozen?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone screen is completely frozen, but I can press the home/power button and it turns on. How do I unlock or reset my iPhone? I have tried pressing the power and home button for thirty minutes.

Comment: Hold the home and power button both at the same time until you see the Apple logo

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar experience with my iPhone: it was showing only the apple when rebooting and never became responsve. I found out was a battery problem and had to change it.